# Two Controllers on the same Web API application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to add one more controller to our existing Web API. The controllers are like

```
public class TDataController : ApiController
{        
   [HttpGet]
   public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(string ROOM, DateTime DOB_GT, DateTime DOB_LT, string STATUS_TYPE)
   { 
     // Code for the controller
   }
}
```

and this is the controller I am trying to add in the same Application

```
public class TDataSubDateController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails(string ROOM, string STATUS_TYPE, DateTime? SUBDATE_GT = null, DateTime? SUBDATE_LT = null)
   {
     //Code for the controller
   }
}
```

When I am trying to call the second controller like

http://localhost:33823/api/TDataSubDate?ROOM=xxx&STATUS_TYPE=xxx&SUBDATE_GT=xxxx&SUBDATE_LT=xxxx

But it throws the `HTTP 404 Page Not Found`error. Do I have to create a different route in the WebConfig.cs. The RouteConfig.cs currently looks like

```
     public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That route config is for MVC, not for Web API.

Comment: How do I handle with two Controller in the same API. To test I used the same code and create seperate Web API and it works perfectly and returns result

Comment: You need to find where your Web API routing is configured. Probably `WebApiConfig.cs` if you used default template. Routing is all explained [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: I have edited my question with the WebConfig.cs. Do I have create a new route here?

Comment: What is the build action for `TDataSubDateController.cs`? Right click the file in Visual Studio's solution explorer and click Properties to see.

Comment: BuildAction is Compile for `TDataSubDateController.cs`. It is the same for both the controllers

Comment: @Sid Theoretically, your code should work.Only thing I can think of it is the parameters. Could you remove all parameters in Getdetails method, and request as `http://localhost:33823/api/TDataSubDate`? If it works, then put back one parameter at a time to see which parameter causes the issue.

Comment: Try using route attributes:  https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: @Win I tied as you said just without any query parameter.When I checked in Fiddler it gives error like {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI `'http://localhost:33823/api/TDataSubDate'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'TDataSubDate'."}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attribute routing if you are using web api 2. For more details please visit https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Here is an example with single controller and multiple actions

```
[RoutePrefix("api/tdata")]
public class TDataController : ApiController
{        
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{ROOM}/preview")]
    public IHttpActionResult Getdetails(string ROOM, [FromUri]DateTime DOB_GT, [FromUri]DateTime DOB_LT, [FromUri]string STATUS_TYPE)
    { 
        return Ok(string.Format("Room {0} Preview", ROOM));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{ROOM}/details")]
    public IHttpActionResult Getdetails(string ROOM, [FromUri]string STATUS_TYPE, [FromUri]DateTime? SUBDATE_GT = null, [FromUri]DateTime? SUBDATE_LT = null)
    {
        return Ok(string.Format("Room {0} Details", ROOM));
    }
}
```

OR into a separate controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/tdatasubdate")]
public class TDataSubDateController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Getdetails([FromUri]string ROOM, [FromUri]string STATUS_TYPE, [FromUri]DateTime? SUBDATE_GT = null, [FromUri]DateTime? SUBDATE_LT = null)
    {
        return Ok(string.Format("Room {0} Details", ROOM));
    }
}
```

And here is how webapiconfig.cs looks like

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// configure global routes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config"></param>
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont we have to change anything in WebConfig.cs ?  I tried to add [Route("api/tdatasubdate")]  And tried to call the API as `http://localhost:33823/api/tdatasubdate?ROOM=xxx&STATUS_TYPE=xxx&SUBDATE_GT=xxxx&SUBDATE_LT=xxxx` It is still not working

Comment: Do you have the following statement as part of your application startup? GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); usually it goes in the global.asax.cs

Comment: Yes I have the statement in Global.asax.cs. And I am able browse through the other controller TData. It is just the issue with the TDataSubDate controller

Comment: What is the url for the controller that works? Can you reproduce the error in another test project?